# Rearrange finite product to isolate variable

Tags: probability, combinations, mathematical-modeling, products

The following equation is used to combine many probabilities of independent, non-mutually-exclusive events such that the probability of each event $i$ is represented by $P(C_i)$. This calculation is performed at each time step in a simulation.

The equation for calculating the combined probability at a given time $t$ for the entire set of events $N$ is:

1.
$$ P(C_1\ \cup\ C_2 \ \cup\ ...\ \cup\ C_N)_t = P({C_1}) + P({C_2}) - P({C_1\ \cap\ C2}) + P({C_3}) - P({C_1\ \cap\ C_3}) - P({C_2\ \cap\ C_3}) - P({C_1\ \cap\ C_2 \ \cap\ C_3})\ ... $$

or

2.
$$ P(C_1\ \cup\ C_2 \ \cup\ ...\ \cup\ C_N)_t = 1 - P(\overline{C_1}) * P(\overline{C_2}) * ... * P(\overline{C_N})$$

or

3.
$$P(C_1\ \cup\ C_2 \ \cup\ ...\ \cup\ C_N)_t = 1-\prod_{i=1}^{N}{ (1 - p_{i}) } $$

where $p_i$ is the probability of occurrence of event $i$ (probability that differs between events).

Furthermore, $p_i$ depends on two factors $p_a$ and $p_{b,i}$ such that
$p_i = p_a*p_{b,i}$.

*While the value of $p_{b,i}$ differs between events,the value of* $p_a$ *is equal between events at a given time* $t$ *(the value of *$p_a$*, however, can change between time steps, which becomes relevant for my question below).* Therefore,

4.
$$P(C_1\ \cup\ C_2 \ \cup\ ...\ \cup\ C_N)_t = 1-\prod_{i=1}^{N}{ (1 - p_\text{a}*p_\text{b, i}) } $$

For simplicity, $P(C1\ \cup\ C_2 \ \cup\ ...\ \cup\ C_N)$ will hereafter be described as $P$.

How, if possible, can the equation be rearranged to isolate $p_a$ so that the probability $P$ at time $t$ ($P_t$) can be calculated as follows using only the values of $P$ at time $t-1$, $p_a$ at time $t$ and $p_a$ at time $t-1$, or:

5.
$$P_t = f(P_{t-1},\ p_{a,t},\ p_{a,t-1})$$?

One attempt of mine converted the product to a sum using logarithms, but I did not manage to isolate the variable $p_a$ as I had hoped through this approach.

I also tried working out examples for small $N$, e.g.:
$$P = 1 - (1-p_a p_{1})(1-p_a p_{2}) \Leftrightarrow P = 1 - (1-p_a p_{1}-p_a p_{2}+p_a^2p_1p_2)$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: What are $p_a$ and $p_{b, i}$? Do they relate somehow to $\mathbb P(C_j)$? For that matter, should $p_a$ also have a second index in the subscript ($i$, probably)?

Comment: Are $N$ and $t$ interchangeable?  If so, does $P_t=1-(1-p_{a,t}p_{b,t})(1-P_{t-1})$?

Comment: Please forgive my bad equation notation.
@AaronMontgomery I edited my post to reflect your questions. 1. $p_a$ and $p_{b,i}$ are the probabilities of two different events that together make up $p_i$. 2. No, $p_a$ should _not_ have a second index in the subscript. While $p_{b,i}$ differs between each event, $p_a$ is constant across all events at a given time $t$.

Comment: @JimB - No, $N$ and $t$ are not interchangable. Perhaps my notation is wrong. I meant $N$ to represent the set of all events $i$ with some probability of occurring at time $t$. The set of events with some probability of occurring changes between time steps, but I know how to account for that by multiplying or dividing from the product term in the equation (as I think you were suggesting in your example). What I need to figure out is how I can calculate the new combined probability $P_t$ based on the values of $p_a$ at times $t$ and $t-1$ and $P_{t-1}$.

Comment: @JimB Does that help?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery does that help?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to return to this, and likely won't for a while. Have you tried working out examples for small $N$, like $N = 2$ or $N =3$? That will probably be enough to show whether what you want to do is feasible. My gut says it is not (again, it's important to note that I haven't tried).